# Rails flash message disappear after few seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am setting my flash message in controller. But flash message is displayed only for few seconds before Vue.js render it's template and flash message disappear. My controller code looks like this:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...

    tournament_match = TournamentMatch.find_by(id: tournament_match_id)
    if tournament_match.score_cards.attach(params['score_cards'])
      flash[:success] = 'Score card uploaded'
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Score card upload failed'
    end
    redirect_to public_results_path
  end
end
```

I want to display flash message bit longer. So how can I display flash message for bit longer? I tried to sleep for 5 seconds in Vue Component in `beforeCreate` life cycle hook but thats also not working. In Rails I tried `flash.keep` but that also didn't work. How can I sleep for 5 seconds in Vue.js before rendering the template ?

Update:

My view for flash message looks like below

```
<div class='flash'>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you post the code to display the flash message? it is mostly javascript code that is showing it for a given period of time.

Comment: @JCorcuera I have updated my question with code for flash message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem by making `div position: fixed`. My final css looks like this

```
.flash {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Vue js was taking all space in the page thats why flash message was invisible, so setting position to fixed makes div remain fixed at the top of page and I can see the flash message.